# How to convert to Double from mantissa and exponent in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, double

I'm trying to create a `double` or `float` from mantissa and exponent in C++; i.e: I have this number: `1472E-2` (Mantissa = 1472 Exponent = -2).

I'm trying to get this number: 14.72; the purpose of this is only to print these numbers.

I've tried `ldexp` and `std::setprecision`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have human-readable scientific notation (with a decimal exponent) and not the binary exponent that `double` uses internally.  That's why `ldexp` did not work for you.

If you have the string `"1472e-2"` you can use `strtod` to parse it, resulting in `14.72`

If you have 1472 and -2 in two separate variables, you can just apply the definition of scientific notation

```
double z = x * pow(10.0, y);
```